# Return String And Use It In Every Differnt String

Tags: java, android

```
public void a(){

        File dir = new File("/mnt/sdcard/files");
        String[] children = dir.list();

        for (String s : children){

            if(s.contains("cache")){

            System.out.println(s);

            // Means Found
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }

        // Means No Found
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
```

what i am actually looking for is that like

- i have many files in "/mnt/sdcard/files" here
- and i want to search the file which contains some known name lets take "Cache" 
  which i can list like this

> System.out.println(s);

The output will be

> - cache.bin
> - newcachete.txt
> - filecache

something like this

but what i actually want is that this function returns full name of files which includes word "cache" and assigning it value in **different string** in another function

for example if this function return String = newcachete.txt so that i can assign its value in another function like this

```
public void newfunction(){

String new = a();
// this string will contain newcachete.txt

}
```

but as there maybe many files conataining this name so i wanted to return all file names which i can assign in new function

for example

```
public void newfunction(){

String new = a();
// this string will contain newcachete.txt
// and like that i want it to conatain every different name
/*
String a = cachenew.bin;
String b = filecachete.txt;
*/

}
```

in different functions
any possible way ?

thanks for your answers i appreciate it for giving me your time :)

im looking for better answer

Comment: you can store it in array.

Comment: could you write some code help ?

Comment: what is  cachenew.bin?

Comment: it is name of file i took randomly :)

Comment: i edited as required now it will clean up and make you understand better :)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
public List a(){

    File dir = new File("/mnt/sdcard/files");
    String[] children = dir.list();
    ArrayList <String> files = new ArrayList <String> ();

    for (String s : children){

        if(s.contains("cache")){

          System.out.println(s);
          files.add (s);

        }
    }

    return files;
}
```

Comment: but how could i use it in next function like String a = a()[0] index 0 and [1]; something like that

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking

Comment: i mean the list add all names together ,what im looking for is that to put different value in different String, like String a = contains first cache file and String b = contains second cache file but list results in [cache1,cache2] but i want each of them in different string

Answer (score 0):

If the names `new` and `old` carry some meaning, you can return a `Map<String,String>` where the key is the names (e.g., `new` and `old`) and the values the file names.

For instance, in your example

> String a = cachenew.bin; String b = cacheold.bin;
>
> so that i can use
>
> String new = a; String old = b;

You can write (assuming `cachenew.bin` and `cacheold.bin` are variables, as you wrote it):

```
public Map<String,String> a() {
  ...


    Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<String,String>();

    result.put("new", cachenew.bin);
    result.put("old", cacheold.bin);

    return result;
}
```

And then use it as

```
Map<String, String> res = a();

String newS = res.get("new");   // "new" is not a good variable name :-)
String oldS = res.get("old");
```

Comment: i would give this one vote up as that will work as well but somehow i fixed it myself to make it simple ,appreciate your time and effort bro :))))